# Styling the default tooltip in joomla 3.6.X

Tags: joomla-3.x, css

Does any know how to edit the default tooltip in joomla 3.6, i cant seem to find the classes in the CSS files.

Comment: Are you using a specific template that has custom tooltips?  If not, It is not possible to style the default browser ones with CSS alone.

Comment: i'm using the standard template that came with joomla 'protostar'

Comment: I take it i need a template with bootstrap

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, if your template has a `custom.css` file, open it, else create this file in your template's CSS directory.

The following code you'll need to edit the base styling of the tooltip is here:

```
.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1030;
  display: block;
  font-size: 11px;
  line-height: 1.4;
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  visibility: visible;
}

.tooltip.in {
  opacity: 0.8;
  filter: alpha(opacity=80);
}

.tooltip-inner {
  max-width: 200px;
  padding: 8px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #000000;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
     -moz-border-radius: 4px;
          border-radius: 4px;
}
```

If you also wish to edit the tooltip arrows, you'll need this too:

```
.tooltip-arrow {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-style: solid;
}

.tooltip.top .tooltip-arrow {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-top-color: #000000;
  border-width: 5px 5px 0;
}

.tooltip.right .tooltip-arrow {
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  margin-top: -5px;
  border-right-color: #000000;
  border-width: 5px 5px 5px 0;
}

.tooltip.left .tooltip-arrow {
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  margin-top: -5px;
  border-left-color: #000000;
  border-width: 5px 0 5px 5px;
}
```

Change the styling to whatever suits your needs